# Exclude element when download with dom-to-image library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library to download component as a png image. However I want some elements to be excluded from downloaded image like a close button, etc

I tried with this approach, to set visible true/false and to hide it with CSS:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(true);

    const closeClassName = classNames(classes.visible, {
        [classes.hidden]: visible === false,
    });

    const downloadTemperaturesGraph = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (chartRef.current) {
            setVisible(false);
            domtoimage.toBlob(chartRef.current, { bgcolor: 'white' }).then((blob) => {
                fileDownload(blob, `${title}.png`);
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
                setVisible(true);
            });
        }
    }, [chartRef, title]);
```

Is there any better way to do it? Could this be done with library's filter option?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with filter option:

```
 const closeRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

 const downloadTemperaturesGraph = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (chartRef.current) {
            domtoimage
                .toBlob(chartRef.current, {
                    bgcolor: 'white',
                    filter: (node: Node) => node !== closeRef.current,
                })
                .then((blob) => {
                    fileDownload(blob, `${title}.png`);
                });
        }
    }, [chartRef, title]);
```